# C#: Check boxes

Tags: c#, checkbox

I have 4 check boxes. One or all can be selected for the program to do its thing. Right now I only have if statements for when only one of them is selected. if I were to do if statements for all situations, I will need 24. Is there an easier way?

Comment: There may be an easier way. If you show us the code you have now, we might be able to help.

Comment: the real question is how did you get 24 possible values for 4 checkboxes?

Comment: Heheh, they should be 15 in fact... if at least one checkbox must be enabled.

Comment: I did 4! which is 24 that's how

Comment: Your question should show some code what you've tried. To be honest, the question is quite confusing to understand as to what you're trying to do and where you're stuck at. If you're looking for a solution to your problem, provide as much details you can in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `Enum` to hold the checked values

```
[Flags]
enum BoxesChecked
{ None = 0, First = 1, Second = 2, Third = 4, Fourth = 8 }

...

var boxesChecked = BoxesChecked.None; 
if (box1.Checked)
    boxesChecked |= BoxesChecked.First;
```

Then make a map of associated actions and retrieve the one that you need based on the given combination

```
var actionsMap = new Dictionary<BoxesChecked, Action>
{ 
    { BoxesChecked.First | BoxesChecked.Second, DoSomething },
    { BoxesChecked.Second | BoxesChecked.Fourth, DoSomethingElse },
    ...
};

var action = actionsMap[boxesChecked];
```